# What can be done with a question & bounty where single answer is already part of the question?

Tags: discussion, bounties, wrong-answers

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40672125/add-div-with-dynamic-vergejs-viewport-values-to-html) question of mine has a bounty of 50 points and received a single answer so far. However the answer is already part of the original quesiton. Additionally the answer also does not solve the question at all and does not include a jsfiddle as outlined in the bounty description.

What can be done now? Left a comment on the answer explaining why the answer is not valid. So far no reaction from the person that posted the answer.

Dont mind loosing the bounty, however I come here to learn form great answers, hence I thought putting a bounty might give me an answer that solves the problem and teaches me how to solve such a problem applicable to similar scenarios in the future.

1. Should I close the question altogether and go back to study this myself?
2. Is the question too specific?
3. What happens if the question does not receive another answer or an edit after 7 days, meaning will the bounty automatically be given to the single answer despite not being valid?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot close the question, as it has a pending bounty. It's a *detailed* question, but not necessarily too specific. As for the answer you do not like:

> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted).

[(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

As long as its score stays below 2, the bounty will not be awarded to it.